# exporting a stylesheet using ES6

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hmm, I didn't find anything elsewhere when researching this one. But, I'd like to export a stylesheet to the rest of my app. The following is ES5 and I want to convert it over to ES6. Even [facebook.github](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/) isn't clear on this one. My ES5 code is:

```
var fontFamily = 'Comic Sans MS, Lucida Handwriting, cursive';
var background = 'pink url("https://media.giphy.com/media/oyr89uTOBNVbG/giphy.gif") fixed';
var fontSize   = '4em';
var padding = '45px 0';
var color  = 'green';

module.exports = {
  fontFamily: fontFamily,
  background: background,
  fontSize: fontSize,
  padding: padding,
  color: color
};
```

Can anyone help on this one? So far I'm trying:

```
export default {
  fontFamily: fontFamily,
  background: background,
  fontSize: fontSize,
  padding: padding,
  color: color
};
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What would be different in ES6 apart from maybe just using let/const instead of var?

Comment: Why is it important at all that this one small component is in ES6?

Comment: And the problem is? This should work `export default {fontFamily, background, etc}`

Comment: You should only use the `default` keyword when exporting one module. Removing the `default` should help fix your issue.

Comment: @Dan what do you mean by "exporting one module"? Why would OP need to remove default?

Comment: According to MDN: If we want to export a single value or to have a fallback value for our module, we could use a default export. The User is trying to export 5 values and thus the `default` keyword will not work. I hadn't seen the `module.exports` statement, this for me did work. Perhaps the User is not importing the module correctly.  @Riku has highlighted below how to do just that via ES6 destructuring.

Comment: OP is exporting a single object with 5 properties. It is perfectly valid to make it default.

Comment: Please see in the article about using export "If we want to export a single value... we could use a default export". 5 values are being exported. When writing for instance `export default { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}` and importing via `import { foo, bar } from 'foo'` the values of `foo` and `bar` are `undefined`. Removing the `default` keyword ensures both values are exported correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways how you can do it, but here are two examples.

Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export for detailed information about the export statement.

**Way number 1**

**EXPORTING**

```
export const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'Comic Sans MS, Lucida Handwriting, cursive',
  background: 'pink url("https://media.giphy.com/media/oyr89uTOBNVbG/giphy.gif") fixed',
  fontSize  : '4em',
  padding: '45px 0',
  color : 'green',
};
```

**IMPORTING**

```
import { styles } from './styles';
const fontFamily = styles.fontFamily;
console.log(fontFamily) // Comic Sans MS, Lucida Handwriting, cursive
```

**Way number 2**

**EXPORTING**

```
const fontFamily = 'Comic Sans MS, Lucida Handwriting, cursive';
const background = 'pink url("https://media.giphy.com/media/oyr89uTOBNVbG/giphy.gif") fixed';
const fontSize   = '4em';
const padding = '45px 0';
const color  = 'green';

export { fontFamily, background, fontSize, padding, color };
```

**IMPORTING**

```
import { fontFamily, color } from './styles';
console.log(fontFamily, color); // Comic Sans MS, Lucida Handwriting, cursive green
```